# Special character '~' in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, special-characters

I would like to insert the character `~` in a gnuplot script.

I tried :

```
set label 2 "\~"
```

but it doesn't work
(edit:   i.e. the tilde character does not appear in the printed label)

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes `'\~'` or backslash the backslash in double quotes: `"\\~"`.

Answer (score 1):

~ is a mark-up character for enhanced text processing. Adding \ as an escape character in double quotes would work, as choroba says.

Another answer is to turn off the enhanced text mode for that label:

```
set label 2 "~" noenhanced
```